# Pass a .mat file to cftool

Tags: matlab

I want to launch "cftool" from a figure using the uimenu labled 'cftool'.  I can create a call-back function that will launch the tool by commanding 'cftool', but the thing is I want parameters (vectors) in a .mat data file to be available to the tool i.e. parameters under X data, Y data, and Z data in the "Curve Fitting Tool" GUI.

I know if I launch cftool from Command Window, vectors in the base workspace are visible to the tool.  Can I make vectors visible to the tool as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the variables in the MAT-file to be visible, you'll need to load them in the base workspace. If the load is made from within a function, that's not as straight forward as it would from within a script :

```
function my_function(arg1, arg2,...)
   data = load('filename.mat');
   var_names = fieldnames(data);
   var_values = struct2cell(data);
   cellfun(@(n,v)assignin('base', n, v), var_names, var_values);
   ...
end
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.